# Is there a way to turn on and off the flashlight of front camera?

Tags: java, android, flashlight

I googled to find front flash light to use as a torch but I am not able to find any answer.
Is there a way or not if so ?
How to ?

Comment: Check the `Camera` class in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> Sample for turning on front camera flashlight:

```
CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String cameraId = cameraManager.getCameraIdList()[1]; //Id 1 is front camera
cameraManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
```